# Small gouge in edge of tire...

Tags: tires, safety

Noticed this on one of my summer tires when I took it out a few weeks ago:

[image]

No puncture, no air loss, no balance issues.  There's a *very* small bump next to where I'm holding the coin.  It's so subtle it can't be seen, only felt slowly.

Comment: Don't worry about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a non-issue. There really isn't much more to say.